# Magnific Popup content won't display on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, magnific-popup

I'm working on a site (http://dev.tlkmultimedia.com) using a template that uses magnific popup. I've got vimeo, youtube and photos working on my laptop and I've tested it in iPad/iPhone emulation on desktop browsers. However, when I try it on my actual iPad or iPhone I am met with a blank black lightbox. 
Here's my initialize JS:

```
 // Example with multiple objects
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,

    fixedContentPos: false
});
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help I receive. Not terribly familiar with this plugin and would love to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've tried using the disable on function but that doesn't appear to resolve it.

Comment: Have you got this resolved?